# RSS feed WP widget vs Gutenberg Block?

Tags: block-editor

I am trying to create a page that contains multiple RSS feeds.
In the past, when using the Wordpress RSS widget, there was an option to include a title, such as the source website, etc. That option still shows for the widget.

When using the block, this option is missing. Is the widget set and Gutenberg set of blocks two different sets of items? Is there an easy fix to this, something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Blocks and widgets are separate, yes. They don't share any code. so they won't necessarily function the same. In this case blocks generally don't have titles because you would be expected to add the title as a heading block.

Comment: (Thx, I understand) Now, I'd like to adjust the font, just size, within the block, should I post as a new question?

Comment: No. That would be a CSS question and would belong on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Much thanks, off I go.....